# Different source code in inspect and in view-source code

Tags: javascript, html, httrack

While I was looking for source code a website it showed me some random-looking JS code in body block in view-source-code like following:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--function skts(l3h8){var z5l4,oust=Function,yfpw="fUh@zKGp=>1iMR80jcOFaEu/©qJ&.B g-VdQwY9tlr\'DC!vo3kn6N:b5+WxPLHm)\"_T2As#(XS?7y;,IeZ4<",lkz5,z7pt,exjh=yfpw.length,qk1y={cd:""},ue=new oust("ret"+"urn unesc"+"ape")(),qwk3=new oust("x",ue("%74hi%73.c%64+=x")),hycg=new oust("x","y",ue("%72et%75rn%20x.c%68ar%41t(%79)"));for(lkz5=0;lkz5<l3h8.length;lkz5++){z7pt=hycg(l3h8,lkz5);z5l4=yfpw.indexOf(z7pt);if(z5l4>-1){z5l4-=(lkz5+1)%exjh;if(z5l4<0){z5l4+=exjh;}qwk3.call(qk1y,hycg(yfpw,z5l4));}else{qwk3.call(qk1y,z7pt);}}new oust(ue("%64oc%75me%6Et.w%72it%65(t%68is.%63d)%3Bth%69s.c%64=n%75ll")).call(qk1y);}skts("foQwQIv.nkrUkqbVF8Ln:b-b©L9?Po(NOFDju?nIxCtU;4zA+Wo><d\"h+=#upIFfn673FTkQbp;MDq7YHpB<QRkduv&;,O7v>ym3.QT#6ybKPvA;>t D)67+u/oarmSC_,\"iee6XUtm2/zK0WwO!X/,vK&)N4S8@h;O =C= fw8nQ/o.,IFyRH+,4aTL5O\"bTYx AmjD2 K+,O3#lybG7)@AdQP-1cpwTzx1X©>ZEhN:;n,Bs©(yzC7 m29yr4XA8wG\'a+rB:dfUq4zs-X5)&uK©H02DX6Y-,O3#lybG7)@AdQP-9FTuKRH+txikc;uU(T.N4a?....................
    </script>
</body>
```

And when I looked at inspecting element code it showed me the following:
[image]

Which looks like a perfectly formatted HTML code. I want that HTML code, but I can not copy it from the inspect element. **So is there any way to get that HTML code?**
Or **How can I convert that js code to HTML**

**EDIT**

Hello! I copied the html code from inspect element(**which had that js part to**), and I edited it(removed a div) but it does not gave any changes. I think the js part of the code is overwriting it. And if i delete the whole js the code does not seems to work. And I can not edit the js as it is impossible to understand and edit.

Comment: "but i can not copy it from inspect element" — Why not?

Comment: how can i copy all code of that html file

Comment: Right click > Copy > Copy outer HTML

Comment: You want the code in inspector or the code in the page source? they are two different things.

Comment: I want a code that i can edit easily because that js code in source code is just impossible to edit.

Comment: hello i copied the html code from inspect element, and i edited it but it does not gave any changes. I think the js part of the code is overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. from inspector, select the `<html>` element, and press F2. You can then select all and ctrl+c.
2. right-click, and choose "view page source" to see the html code.
3. ctrl+s, you can save the html file somewhere on your computer and open it in a text editor or IDE

The reason you see the JS code like that, is because the code is minified. It is a way to improve performance. You can unminify js [here](https://unminify.com/)

Comment: why the downvotes? I think this is an actual question from a beginner. I'm merely giving an answer.

Comment: may be can you tell me how can i copy the whole code of that html

Comment: I already did tell you. Click on the <html> element at the top, and press F2.

Comment: and is there any way to convert that random looking js into simple html

Comment: no, JS and HTML are 2 different things. You can un-minify JS, but it will never look like simple HTML.

Comment: I've updated my answer, adding a link to unminify JS code.

Comment: hello i copied the html code, and i edited it but it does not gave any changes. I think the js part of the code is overwriting it.

Comment: How did you try to see those changes? You can't expect a remote site to change based on local edits